# Is it grammatically right to say this

Tags: grammar, irregular-plurals

So for the audience, now the difficulty lies in deciding which opinion to agree with and which "**experts**" seem the most credible. Is it right to use the plural form of expert?

Comment: If there are more than one expert, why would it not be right to use the plural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtle grammar changes suggested:

> So for the audience, the difficulty lies in deciding which *opinions*
>   to agree with and which *experts* **seem** most credible.

and

> So for the audience, the difficulty lies in deciding which *opinion*
>   to agree with and which *expert* **seems** most credible.

The verb **seem** [ I + adv/prep, L ] can be tricky  [cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/seem). Also watch to keep nouns in a sentence all plural or singular.

Comment: So I can use the plural form of a noun after "which"? I thought I can only use singular form of a noun after "which".

Comment: You can definitely use a plural noun after “which”.  For example: “I like any food which doctors suggest.”

Comment: @jbeldock That's a different use of *which*. But you can have "*Which animal**s** do you like?*"

Comment: Good point!  Or the old standby “I’m trying to decide which shoes to wear today.”